# Rails bulk update with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to update some records in bulk using ActiveRecord's `#update_all`.

```
values = {}
values[:developer_id] = value
values[:status] = 2 # if issue.status == 1
issues.update_all(values)
```

I need to make sure to update the status only if its value is 1, so I am not sure how I can achieve that without looping on the issues and check each one and update the columns (n+1) queries.

**EDIT**

To make the question clear, I need to update all developer_id columns for **all issues** and update the status only if the status == 1.

**How to update in bulk and applying this condition at the same time?**

Comment: Just so this makes sense, the comment was made that the OP only wants to update the status if the status is 1 but wants to update the developer_id in all cases. For that case you will probably need to use handwritten SQL similar to `status = CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE status END`. This will likely be different depending on the database you are using.

Comment: I edited the question, I thought it's clear, sorry for that.

Comment: You can't do that in one query. You have to do it in two queries. First update the `developer_id` and then the `status`. Why does it have to be one query?

Answer (score 1):

Use active record to select the only rows whose `status` is `1`, then update them in bulk.

```
issues = Issue.where(status: 1)
```

or chain it with `update_all`

```
issues.where(status: 1).update_all(values)
```

Both will query directly inside database, so N+1 shouldn't happen.

Comment: Umm, in that case at least two query would be needed to avoid N+1 I guess. One for all data, and another for conditional data.